# Have we ever seen flash backs of Mirajane using Satans Soul when she was little?

Tags: fairy-tail

I was just wondering on this, but has there actually ever been any sightings (E.g. Flash backs in the Mangas of Mirajane using Satans Soul when she was little)? We are probably talking around the time before Lisanna "died".

Answer (score 1):

As per data given in the newer chapters of the manga, [Mirajane](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Mirajane_Strauss) got her Satan soul power when she accidentally absorbed a demon which was residing in their village. Initially she was unable to control her Satan soul power and her hand was always in the form of demon. She was ostracized in her village due to which she was forced to move out of her house. She along with lisanna and elfman somehow made to fairy tail guild where master makarov told her about her power and she learns how to control it. then afterwords her siblings also learned Satan magic so that she doesn't feel out of place.

[image: Mira using Satan Soul.]